# Grub, usb multiboot ubuntu and windows 10 installation disk

Tags: linux, usb, windows, grub

I made usb disk multiboot installation, ubuntu and windows 10.

```
sudo parted -s /dev/sdb mklabel msdos

sudo parted -s /dev/sdb mkpart primary 1MiB 551MiB

sudo parted -s /dev/sdb set 1 esp on
sudo parted -s /dev/sdb set 1 boot on

sudo mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdb1
sudo parted -s /dev/sdb mkpart primary 551MiB 100%

sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb2

sudo mkdir /media/{efi,data}

sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/efi
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/data

sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --boot-directory="/media/data/boot" /dev/sdb
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --recheck --removable --efi-directory="/media/efi" --boot-directory="/media/data/boot"
```

Then I made folder for iso and copied there needed isos.

```
sudo mkdir /media/data/boot/iso
sudo chown 1000:1000 /media/data/boot/iso

hosek@yoga:/media$ ls -la /media/data/boot/iso/
total 7911028
drwxr-xr-x 2 hosek hosek       4096 čen 23 10:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root        4096 čen 23 10:38 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hosek hosek 3285123072 dub 20 09:09 ubuntustudio-19.04-dvd-amd64.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hosek hosek 4815753216 čen 13 09:24 Win10_1903_V1_Czech_x64.iso
hosek@yoga:/media$
```

Now I insert this to **/media/data/boot/grub/grub.cfg** file.

```
menuentry "ubuntustudio-19.04-dvd-amd64.iso" {
isofile="/boot/iso/ubuntustudio-19.04-dvd-amd64.iso"
loopback loop "${isofile}"
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename="${isofile}" file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntustudio.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}

menuentry "Win10_1903_V1_Czech_x64.iso" {
# Insert modules needed in order to access the iso-file
insmod part_gpt
#insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
insmod ext4
# Insert module needed in order to find partition
insmod search_fs_uuid

# Set UUID of partition with the iso-image
# and let grub2 find the partition
# (save it's identifier to the variable $root)
set uuid="8ff5d218-2b0c-471c-8356-98686a351111"
search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid $uuid

# Mount the iso image by addressing it with (partition)/path
set iso=/boot/iso/Win10_1903_V1_Czech_x64.iso
loopback loop ($root)$iso

# boot (chain-load) the image using the cdboot.efi file located
# on the win10-image
chainloader (loop)/efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi
}
```

When I restart computer and boot from usb, it shows me menu.

```
ubuntustudio-19.04-dvd-amd64.iso
Win10_1903_V1_Czech_x64.iso
```

When I choose ubuntustudio-19.04-dvd-amd64.iso, it is ok.
But when I choose Win10_1903_V1_Czech_x64.iso, it shows me, that file **/efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi** not found.

Where could be the problem? And what about Windows 7 installation, is the menuantry for grub same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While you indeed cannot boot and install Windows from an ISO file, you can do this:

1. Create a GPT
2. Create two partitions and create file-systems:

   1. a large partition with NTFS (type 0x0700, must be the first partition else Windows Setup might not see it)
   2. a small (10 MB suffices for FAT16, 100 MB for FAT32) partition with FAT (type 0xef00, EFI System Partition)
3. Download [NFTS:UEFI](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/tree/master/res/uefi), extract the files and place them into the ESP so FAT16:\efi\boot\bootx64.efi exists.
4. Extract the contents of a Windows Setup .iso to the NTFS partition
5. Move NTFS:\efi\boot\bootx64.efi to NTFS:\efi\boot\windows.efi.
6. Temporarily rename FAT:\efi to move NTFS:UEFI out of the way.
7. Install grub to the FAT ESP with the --removable option.
8. Move FAT:\efi to NTFS:\efi, merging the contents (remember we renamed Microsoft's grubx64.efi).
9. Undo step 6.
10. Create a grub.cfg at FAT:\boot\grub\grub.cfg:

    ```
     menuentry "Windows 10 Setup EFI" {
         search --file --set=root --no-floppy /efi/boot/windows.efi
         chainloader /efi/boot/windows.efi
     }
    ```
11. Create the file FAT:/.disk/info (in removable mode, grub will look for this file to identify its "boot" partition).
12. Enjoy your Windows Setup from your .iso stick.

Notes:

- Windows Setup will not work on non-EFI systems or CSM mode.
- [rufus](http://rufus.ie/) can do steps 1 to 4 for you.
- You can skip all the steps involving NTFS:UEFI iff your EFI can read NTFS directly.
- You can also add a third partition for a Linux "to go" installation.

I occasionally update the more in-depth [article at my blog](https://ssl.hehoe.de/artikel/blog/usb-stick-mit-bootbarem-linux-ubuntu-iso-und-windows-setup.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367011/boot-windows-7-iso-from-grub2). As far as I could know, you can't boot a Windows ISO with GRUB.

> Technically installing from windows's .iso file can't be possible. You
>   can boot from the .iso using grub but after that Windows will loss
>   contact with the mounted location or it is not capable of it. So both
>   grub & Windows should aware of mount and boot. Currently Windows
>   doesn't support.

What I know works, is to copy the contents to your USB root, not in a subfolder, and then use a menu like this:

```
menuentry "Windows installer" {
  set root='hd01'
  insmod ntldr
  ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

I haven't been able to boot from EFI, and I think is not possible either.

Comment: Thank you. So I need to create special partition for windows os and copy to root? Or can I just extract windows folder to usb data partition and set up the path? Thanks.

Comment: Give me some time to try again. If a remember correctly, windows 7 won't work on a different partition than the root. I mean, it boots, but the installer won't detect the hard disk. With windows 10, I think that you can put it in a new partition. I'll check it now.

Comment: Yes, I remember this issue about w7 disk problem. Ok, I will wait. Let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: It was like that. Windows 7 in a different partition will boot but won't detect the hd. Windows 10 is ok on a different partition.

Comment: Ok, so if is not another solution for w7, then good bye w7. Thank you for answer.